# Deploy Angular 4 App on windows

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to deploy my angular application on windows server for that i am using the express server .

I have configured my server.js file like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4200);

app.get('*/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));    
})

console.log('App is listing on ' + 4200);
```

Also, i have deployed the content that was produced using the ng build command inside dist.

I can successfully able to access the application when i enter http://localhost:4200 in my browser.

But, the problem what i am facing here is the proxy server is not getting created which was used to be created when i was using :

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config local-proxy.config.json",
```

But, now since i am not calling ng serve instead of this i am calling node server.js which is serving my application on server.

```
"start": "node server.js --proxy-config local-proxy.config.json",
```

Can someone can help me please.

Comment: when you make npm start your proxy is not called. It's because --proxy is used for development purpose. When you run ng build it creates bundle list (dist). On server you have configured that it looks for files in /dist. Basicly you don't need to create proxy because you are already on that server and requests won't be denied by CORS.

Comment: @Vinko Vorih But, for now i am running both backend and frontend on my local system and its creating problem.

Comment: if you run node server it will call /dist/index.html. Can you explain what problem are you experiencing. Why would you want to create a local-proxy on something that is inside of bundle?

Comment: @VinkoVorih my backend request are failing i am getting                   Request URL:http://localhost:4200/app/rest/v1/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found. But, url is correct my backend is also running. But its running on 8085 port

Comment: @VinkoVorih So,As per server.js i am running my application on 4200 port and the same port is used for making a backebnd call http://localhost:4200/app/rest/v1/login but actually my backend is running on http://localhost:8085/app/rest/v1/login. I hope this will make something clear for you.

Comment: what you've described is that you are using 2 backends?

Comment: @VinkoVorih i am not using two backend the api that is generated from the UI call is on 4200 port but my actual backend is running on 8085 port because of the port issue it looks two different URL.